# How can I limit the length of a HighCharts PlotLine on the Y-Axis for a BoxPlot?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highchairs 3.0 to create a graph that has N Boxes on it. So far so good.  However, one of the user desires is to draw a few plotLines (based on values on the Yaxis) for each Box on the graph.  The catch is that the information is different for each of the boxes, so they want the plotLine to just extend from the start of the box on the left side (x-axis basis) to the right of the single box.

Highchairs by default draws the y-axis plotLines (and plotBands, looked at those too) all the way from left to right, causing a very chaotic chart indeed!

Is there a way to limit the length (start / end on the x-axis I guess) of a plotLine in a box plot to just the width of the box?? I guess I basically want to overlay lines onto the area of each Box on the graph.

Thanks!

Comment: Not with `plotLines` or `plotBands`. You could do this with 2 points connected by a line - requires a new series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way that I have found to do this is by extending the marker symbol types to create a horizontal line.
Use this as the marker symbol type for a scatter series to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.hline = function(x, y, width, height) {
    return ['M',x ,y + height / 2,'L',x+width,y + width / 2];
};
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/m85yv3aq/

Required inputs of: radius, lineWidth, color

((also a useful way to build bullet charts:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/UGs2E/

))

Comment: That is an amazing and beautiful (and perfect) solution!  Man -- I never would have guessed HighCharts let you do this neat stuff!  Thanks!

Comment: The credit for the original code (as posted in the answer) goes to Torstein himself, who provided it when I was asking for a way to set up the bullet chart. If you can work out the paths to draw, you can make this draw any marker shape you want :)

Comment: BTW -- I would happily up-vote the answer .. but I don't have enough ranking yet! Doh! :)

Comment: @sjmcdowall - I believe you can still mark this as the "Accepted Answer" (since you asked the question) even if you don't have enough reputation to vote.

Comment: @mralexlau - thanks! Didn't know I could do that!  Done!

Comment: What if the xAxis type is datetime?

Comment: @RaeinHashemi x axis type has no bearing on this issue. It's just another marker type - you supply it the same x and y values you would any other.