# How can I add benchmarks to columns in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a column chart made with Highcharts and I want to add lines associated with each column showing benchmarks. I know Highcharts has a concept of plot lines, where there is one benchmark value given for the whole chart, but in my case, each column needs it's own benchmark. Here is a super simple example of how I want this to look:

[image: bar chart with benchmarks]

I have some ideas of how I could do this, but they all seem like kind of indirect solutions. I could implement the benchmark lines as another column series, and style them so that only the top of the column shows, or as a scatter series where the "points" are actually lines, but I don't know if either of those are possible and they sound like a complicated way to do something simple. Hopefully I'm just missing an obvious feature of Highcharts.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: A second series is the way to do it. There is no 'line' marker type, but you can create a custom marker for a scatter series. See these answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669241/how-can-i-limit-the-length-of-a-highcharts-plotline-on-the-y-axis-for-a-boxplot/30670879#30670879 | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894828/i-want-to-add-a-line-to-each-column-in-a-highcharts-column-chart/25897437#25897437

Comment: Thanks, that definitely would work. I wish there was a built in way to do that in Highcharts, but if not, that's what I may have to do!

Comment: That's as close to built in as there is at this point. Let's call it "mostly built-in" ;)

Comment: You can post your suggestion in our uservoice service: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Comment: Great, will do. Thanks @SebastianBochan

Comment: Posted this here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/14895030-create-a-way-to-add-benchmarks-to-individual-colum for anyone who wants to follow it. For now, the above suggestions are fine.